# Register new devices for the same enterprise account in Apple

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store

We have an account in our company; via this account we submit our applications in the App Store.

I have already done the procedure (new account, provisioning profiles etc) for an iPhone4, therefore I am able to create applications.

I have a couple of new devices (an iPad and an iPhone5) and I would like to enable those new devices to be certified in order to create applications as well (those are my devices).

What is needed to register the new devices? The UDID? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all, with enterprise account, you cant submit your apps to appstore so if you are submitting apps to appstore, you do not have a enterprise account. second, you need UDIDs to add these account devices to developer provisioning profiles.

Comment: I updated my question, to reflect your comment. Finally, I just need the UDID of the new devices only, correct?

Comment: yes that's correct...only the UDIDs